CarPlay integration for a VoIP app without a template
Our VoIP app already implements CallKit and Siri. So, within the iPhone, we can start calls using Siri. These are prerequisites for the CarPlay integration.
Our deployment target is iOS 14, so to integrate CarPlay, the implementation of scenes is a requirement. However, our app should remain a single-window app. So, I've implemented scenes adding a single main scene.
When I tap on my app in the CarPlay Simulator, it opens a blank window. Then, it crashes with the error: "Application does not implement CarPlay template application lifecycle methods in its scene delegate."
All the third-party VoIP apps I've tried, instead of opening a window, ask you through Siri who you would like to call. So, it seems to be possible to avoid implementing a CarPlay template and just activate Siri. How can I obtain this behavior?

Do you have the com.apple.developer.carplay-calling entitlement from Apple?

@Paulw11 Yes. As described in my answer, unfortunately, it's no longer possible to build a CarPlay app without implementing templates.

I asked the same question in the Apple Developer Forum and here's the answer:

Hi, your app needs to implement the CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate
methods. When your app receives a CarPlay scene, it should present a
root template - usually a tab bar template or a list template.
The legacy VOIP apps you tried are likely using a Siri API that
launches straight to Siri when the app is opened. This API has been
deprecated, and modern communications apps need to present templates.

